# Zend Framework 3 [UnexpectedValueException] Invalid version string "^1.1.0"

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework3

I am trying to install Zend Framework 3 in Windows 7. I downloded the Skeleton from Git and run `composer install`. But getting the error
`[UnexpectedValueException] Invalid version string "^1.1.0"`.

Details:
PHP Version 5.6.3,
XAMPP Version 5.6.3

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what command you ran and why you downloaded the skeleton. The preferred way to install the skeleton is with composer:

```
composer create-project zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install
```

More info can be found on https://framework.zend.com/downloads/skeleton-app